# How can use flex instead of height: 100%?

Tags: css

I do not prefer using width and height as 100%.
I am using the flex instead of % as for example.

```
div {
    flex: 0 0 100%;   // Instead of width: 100%;
}
```

Regarding the height, I used flex as follows.

```
div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;   // this div height is more than the screen height, so it has a scroll y
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 0 0 100%;    // Instead of height: 100%;
}
```

When I used height: 100%, scroll y is good work but when I used flex, it doesn't work the scroll y(as fixed size).
How can work scroll y using flex or any method instead of 100%?

Comment: Please add some HTML. Without it, CSS is useless. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: flex can only be used if (and only if) the parent is a flex container